# Navigate to root from child outlet angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angularfire2, angular-routing

The issue is that I want navigate to app root from within a child route.

This is my structure:

```
export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
   { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
   { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, resolve: { data: UserResolver},
     children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'projects', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent, resolve: { data: UserResolver}},
        { path: 'addproject', component: AddprojectComponent, resolve: { data: UserResolver}},
        { path: 'updateproject/:key', component: AddprojectComponent, resolve: { data: UserResolver}},
        { path: 'network', component: NetworkComponent, resolve: { data: UserResolver}},
        { path: 'figures', component: FiguresComponent, resolve: { data: UserResolver}},
        { path: 'user', component: UserComponent,  resolve: { data: UserResolver}}
     ]
   },
   { path: 'forgot', component: ForgotComponent },
];
```

This is the app.compenent.html:

```
<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

And this is the dashboard.component.ts:

```
<div class="dashboard-content-wrapper">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I have a button in the UserComponent that I expect to navigate to the login page since it is root, but I can't get passed the dashboard component??

```
deleteProfile() {
    this.route.navigate(['/'])
}
```

Comment: Just a guess and not supposed to be taken as answer, try: `this.route.navigate(['./../'], {relativeTo:this.activatedRoute})`

Comment: If you want to go to the login component, then why not navigate directly to the login component?

Comment: share your auth guard ?

Comment: Because it is not possible as I am inside the UserComponent that is a child of the DashboardComenent, so the click is happening inside a child outlet.

Comment: This is my auth guard: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nutpqu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauth.guard.ts

Answer (score 3):

RE:

> Because it is not possible as I am inside the UserComponent that is a
>   child of the DashboardComenent, so the click is happening inside a
>   child outlet.

It should be possible. I do this all of the time.

Just be sure to specify the slash in the path so it is not relative to its current location.

So something like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to route relative to existing `route`.

```
this.route.navigate([ '../../' ], { relativeTo: this.route })
```